# Pandas - Parallelizing astype function

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing

I'm dealing with a huge dataset with lots of features. Those features are actually int type,but since they have `np.nan` values, pandas assigns `float64` type to them.

I'm casting those features to `float32` by iterating every single column. It takes about 10 minutes to complete. Is there any way to speed up this operation?

The data is read from a csv file. There are `object` and `int64` columns in the data.

```
for col in float_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Simply do - `df.astype(np.float32)`?

Comment: Data are read from csv?

Comment: then use `pd.read_csv(file, dtype=float)`

Comment: there are only numeric columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dtype` parameter with dictionary in `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=dict.fromkeys(float_cols, np.float32))
```

Comment: @gunesevitan - Answer is edited, I hope now working faster.